# jQuery Compare 3 items and add the size of the largest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I did a jQuery script to detect the size of 3 boxes. I detect the biggest *height* (it works) and I manage to add the largest size to the three boxes.

Only, it only works when the page loads. I put a *resize*, but when I do a `console.log(maxHeight)`, the value always stays the same, even if I shrink the window. And so, my boxes do not fit.

Can you help me ?

Thank you

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {

var maxHeight = 0;


$('.sliderBlog').each(function(){
    var thisH = $(this).height();
    if (thisH > maxHeight) { maxHeight = thisH; }
});
$('.sliderBlog').height(maxHeight) 
} ).resize();
```

Comment: That's because `maxHeight` is local to the anonymous function you call on `resize`.

Comment: move maxHeight out of `$(window)...`

Comment: You should debounce the call to the resize callback with `setTimeout`. You don't want to spam the browser with many calls.
You could make your code a bit more expressive with functions. Global state should be avoided when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** reset height with `.height("auto")` before comparing them.

You need to reset the height with `.height("auto")`.

Also, you might consider wrapping this code in `$(document).ready()` so it runs when the dom is actually ready.
The *equalizing* feature could be extracted to make it more functional and stateless.
See [this codepen](http://codepen.io/sumi1985/pen/EWVQmJ);

**JavaScript:**

```
var equalize = function(selector){
  var maxHeight = 0;
  $(selector).each(function(idx,el){
    $(el).height("auto"); // resetting height
    var h = $(el).height();
    if (h > maxHeight) { maxHeight = h; }
  });

  $(selector).each(function(idx,el){
    $(el).height(maxHeight);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  equalize(".sliderBlog"); // resize when dom ready

  // register the resize event listener with debounce
  $(window).on("resize", function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
       equalize(".sliderBlog");
    }, 500); // 500ms debounce before calling the function
  });
})
```

NB: Fine tune the debounce time to your need.

Comment: Waow ! **Thank you very much**, your help is greatly appreciated. It works very well, thanks for the tips!

Comment: No worries man. Make it your accepted answer if solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with these

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
var maxHeight = 0;

$('.sliderBlog').each(function(){
   var thisH = $(this).height();
   if (thisH > maxHeight) { maxHeight = thisH; }
});
$('.sliderBlog').height(maxHeight) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be combining two different resize methods.

`$(window).on("resize", function(){});` is a DOM event listener.

`$(selector).resize(function(){});` is a [jQuery method](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

At any rate, what you are looking for is close to what you have. Below I fixed your code and wrapped it in a debounce function ([read here](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) to understand why).

```
var setToMax = debounce(function() {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $('.sliderBlog').each(function(){
        var thisH = $(this).height();
        if (thisH > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = thisH;
        }
    });
    $('.sliderBlog').height(maxHeight) 
}, 250, true);

window.addEventListener('resize', setToMax);

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

You can see a functioning example at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7y6peoxo/3/).

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP original question : the height does not resize when the window shrinks.